# Solving $\sin 3\theta=1/2$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I don't understand where some solutions came from.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am learning precalculus, and I understand how to obtain first two solutions, but I don't understand where did last four solutions came from:

> All values of $\theta$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ that satisfy $\sin 3\theta=1/2$ are
>   $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{18}, \frac{5\pi}{18}, \frac{13\pi}{18}, \frac{17\pi}{18}, \frac{25\pi}{18}, \frac{29\pi}{18}$$

Comment: These trigonometric equations are always solved the same way. First, you write the equation so that both sides have the same trigonometric function:
$$
\sin{3 \theta} = \sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}
$$
After this, you utilize the solution
$$
\sin{x} = \sin{y} \Leftrightarrow x = y + n2\pi \quad \text{or} \quad x = \pi - y + n2\pi
$$
now just plug in the values $x= 3\theta$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: $\sin 3θ$ goes through $3$ periods over the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Each period contains two solutions of the equations, the first two are just the ones from the first period.

Answer (score 1):

Write out $3\theta$: $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\frac{13\pi}{6}$, $\frac{17\pi}{6}$, $\frac{25\pi}{6}$, $\frac{29\pi}{6}$. Now subtract $\frac{\pi}{6}$ from $\frac{13\pi}{6}$, and you get $\frac{12\pi}{6}=2\pi$. The sine function is periodic, with this period. You get all the other by adding $2\pi$ or $4\pi$ to the first solutions.

Maybe a more obvious way of thinking about the problem is to say $\alpha=3\theta$, and find all solutions of $\sin\alpha=\frac 12$ in the interval $[0,6\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\theta \in \left[0, 2\pi\right]\implies 3\theta \in \left[0, 6\pi\right]$$
$$\sin 3\theta = \dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$3\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}+2n\pi, n \in \Bbb Z$$
But $3\theta \in \left[0, 6\pi\right]$, so $$3\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6},\dfrac{5\pi}{6},\dfrac{13\pi}{6},\dfrac{17\pi}{6},\dfrac{25\pi}{6},\dfrac{29\pi}{6}$$
Therefore
$$\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{18}, \dfrac{5\pi}{18}, \dfrac{13\pi}{18},\dfrac{17\pi}{18},\dfrac{25\pi}{18},\dfrac{29\pi}{18}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

When does $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$?

The sine of a directed angle is the $y$-coordinate of the point where its terminal side intersects the unit circle.  Clearly, one solution is when $\theta = \varphi$.  By symmetry, $\sin\theta = \sin(\pi - \theta)$, so $\varphi = \pi - \theta$ is another solution.  Moreover, any angle coterminal with $\theta$ or $\pi - \theta$ will also have the same sine.  Since coterminal angles differ by integer multiples of $2\pi$, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$

> Solve the equation $\sin(3\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

A particular solution of the equation 
$$\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$$
is 
$$\alpha = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
Substituting $3\theta$ for $\alpha$ yields
$$\sin(3\theta) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$
Thus, we have the general solution
\begin{align*}
3\theta & = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & 3\theta & = \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\theta & = \frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}, k \in \mathbb{Z} & 3\theta & = \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
& & \theta & = \frac{5\pi}{18} + \frac{2m\pi}{3}, m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Since we seek solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$, $k = 0, 1, 2$ and $m = 0, 1, 2$, which yields
\begin{align*}
\theta & = \frac{\pi}{18}, \frac{13\pi}{18}, \frac{25\pi}{18} & \theta & = \frac{5\pi}{18}, \frac{17\pi}{18}, \frac{29\pi}{18}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$ 3 \theta = 30^{\circ}, (180-30)^{\circ} $$ to which add multiples of $360^{\circ}$

That is now

$$  \theta = 10^{\circ}, (60-10)^{\circ} $$ to which add multiples of $120^{\circ}.$